# Unilateral SSL with CL+SSL package

Tags: ssl, lisp, common-lisp

In Lispworks on XP when I do:

```
CL-USER 489 > (cl+ssl:make-ssl-client-stream (cl+ssl:stream-fd *standard-output*))
```

I get:

```
Error: A failure in the SSL library occurred on handle #. (Return code: 1)SSL error queue: error:140C5042:SSL routines:SSL_UNDEFINED_FUNCTION:called a function you should not call
```

Is this something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you get libssl32.dll and libeay32.dll files from? I couldn't find working combination either.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities here.

Either you forgot to call some initialization function you should have called before making the stream or there's a bug in CL+SSL, possibly one that only surfaces on Lispworks or Windows XP (probably it's the latter).

Does the CL+SSL test suite run without any problems?

Edit: just tested this on SBCL/Linux, same error. The problem must be with CL+SSL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying it.  I guess this suggests that no one is using CL+SSL for SSL. I wonder what they are using.

Comment: Actually CL+SSL is very popular, being the only portable SSL package for CL. Hunchentoot and Drakma are using it without any problem whatsoever. For example just try (drakma:http-request "https://fortify.net/sslcheck.html")

I checked the Drakma source, it's not much different from what you are trying, but it passes an actual TCP stream returned by either comm:open-tcp-stream (on Lispworks) or usocket:socket-connect (elsewhere).

So I conclude that CL+SSL is sane but you need to figure out how to use it correctly.

Comment: Ugh, Stack Overflow munges my comment text :/ you need to put https and :// in front of the Drakma test URI and remove the semicolon after the closing quote.

Comment: I don't dispute that I need to figure out how to use CL+SSL, but doesn't the fact that the URI you provided works only demonstrate that SSL works on the server side and not necessarily the client?

Comment: Drakma is acting as SSL client. Have I got your question wrong?

Comment: If I go to that URI, aren't I the client? Anyway, I think I have made some progress. If I do:
(connect-toplevel "db" "login" "pwd" #(123 45 67 89) :use-ssl :yes)

I get:

Error: SSL failure in #<COMM:SOCKET-STREAM 200E6D5F>: error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure

Which I think suggests that the problem now may be with SSL and Postgres on the server.

Comment: Clarification about the test URI I gave you: you're not supposed to open the URI in your browser, but to use Drakma to fetch the page.

Have you tried connecting to the Postgres server via SSL using some other tool?

Comment: Sorry about that. I was able to use Drakma to connect to the fortify.net URI using SSL.

Answer (score 1):

The error message here isn't helpful.  I believe the true problem here is that CL+SSL expects a stream of octets, whereas the basic standard input stream in Common Lisp is a stream of characters.  Try to use a stream of octets instead.  This should work in SBCL on Linux:

```
(let ((stdin (sb-sys:make-fd-stream 0
               :input t :buffering :full
               :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)))
  (cl+ssl:make-ssl-client-stream (cl+ssl:stream-fd stdin)))
```

This relies on the fact that Unix has standard input available as file descriptor 0.  I'm not sure on how to perform such a trick on Windows.

For a real application, you probably don't really want to be working from standard input, something like this would work, using the usocket library:

```
(let ((sock (usocket:socket-connect host port :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))))
  (cl+ssl:make-ssl-client-stream (usocket:socket-stream sock)))
```

Comment: actually  `(let ((sock (usocket:socket-connect "www.google.com" 80 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))))
  (cl+ssl:make-ssl-client-stream (usocket:socket-stream sock)))`
still get the same error

Comment: How about using port 443 for SSL over HTTP?